# How to sync data with MongoDb and know the status while a document is being created/updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing a MERN chat app and trying to replicate the feature which WhatsApp provides -> message sent/seen status, so for that I need to check **whether the message I/user sent is successfully synced/updated/created in my MongoDB**, I know similar functionality can be achieved in `AWS Amplify` using the event `outboxMutationEnqueued` which says `Dispatched when a local change has been newly staged for synchronization with the cloud`, so it works like whenever we are trying to push something to synchronize with the cloud, this event is going to be fired, and once it is finished, `outboxMutationProcessed` is going to be triggered which says `Dispatched when a local change has finished syncrhonization with the cloud and is updated locally`.

So we can listen to these events whenever we are trying to send a message, and once our message mutation is processed we are going to receive `outboxMutationProcessed`, and then we can update the status of the message to `sent` or `single tick` or `delivered`.

```
import Amplify, {Hub} from 'aws-amplify';

useEffect(() => {
  const listener = Hub.listen('datastore', async (hubData) => {
    const {event, data} = hubData.payload;
    if (event === 'networkStatus') {
      console.log('User has a network connection: ', data.active);
    }
    if (event === 'outboxMutationProcessed') {
      if (data.model === Message)
        console.log('Mutation has been synced with the cloud: ', data);
        // set the message status to delivered.
    }
  })
  return () => listener();
}, []);
```

So, the question, do we have something similar in `MongoDB`? I'm currently using React Native, Node, Express, Sockets, Mongoose, MongoDB.

Currently, my API end point and collections (for creating a new message and saving in to db):

I have 3 collections: `users`, 'messages', 'chatRooms'.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const MessageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  roomId: String,
  senderId: String,
  text: String,
  status: String, // INQUEUE, SENT, DELIVERED, READ
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);

router.post('/create_message', checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
  const {chatRoomId, senderId, text} = req.body;
  try {
    const message = new Message({
      chatRoomId,
      senderId,
      text,
    });
    const result = await message.save();

    return res.status(200).json({
      type: 'success',
      data: result,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(422).send({error: `${error.message}`});
  }
});

// SOCKET IMPLEMENTATION FOR REALTIME FEATURE

socket.on('listener', async data => {
  io.to(id).emit('new_message', data);
  const message = new Message({
    chatRoomId: data.roomId,
    senderId: data.senderId,
    text: data.text,
    status: data.status, // data.status = 'INQUEUE'
  });
  await message.save();
  // maybe something here...? not sure
  // data.status = 'SENT' after successful creation of document.
});
```

Maybe an event which we can fire, during the `await message.save(...something here...)`, and if it is successfully saved in our DB, we can send it to our frontend or using socket?

If anyone could provide an example, it would be really helpful!

Comment: have you looked at mongodb [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Mongo.watch/)?

Comment: @knicholas yes, but it's for listening to changes right? I need the synchronization functionality not just listening to document changes... Or could you provide an example for the same?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I changed this up a bit.

schemas:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  online: Boolean,
  isActive: Boolean,
})

const RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  members: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }],
})

const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  roomId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'rooms' },
  senderId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
  text: String,
  deliveredTo: [{ user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }, timestamp: Date }],
  readBy: [{ user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }, timestamp: Date }],
})
```

app.js

```
Mongo.connect(uri, (err, client) => {
  mongoose.connect(uri)
  socketClient.on('connection', socket => {
    //
    //on load all users for login select
    User.find().then(users => socket.emit('users', users))
....
  //
  //setting pipeline for readStream to only watch for changes in the messages collection
 //where the roomId field is the current room the user has loaded
 //setting fulldocument : 'updateLookup' option will always return the fulldocuemnt with any updates
 //without this, the fulldocument will only be returned on our insert change
 const pipeline = [{ $match: { 'fullDocument.roomId': ObjectId(room.id) } }]
 const collection = client.db('chat').collection('messages')
 const messageStream = collection.watch(pipeline, { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' })
 messageStream.on('change', async function (change) {
 const updates = change.updateDescription?.updatedFields
 //
 //if a new document is created in messages, then push that message to the client
 if (change.operationType.match(/insert/i)) {
 const doc = await Message.findById(change.fullDocument._id).populate(
              'deliveredTo.user readBy.user'
            )
 const status = await getStatus(doc, room.id)
 socket.emit('push message', { doc, status: status })
 //
 //if delivered to has been updated on a message then send to client
          } else if (updates?.deliveredTo) {
 const status = await getStatus(change.fullDocument, room.id)
 socket.emit('status change', {
              id: change.fullDocument._id,
              status: status,
              user: change.fullDocument.senderId,
            })
 } else if (updates?.readBy) {
 //
 //if readby has been updated on a message then send to client
          
      const status = await getStatus(change.fullDocument, room.id)
      socket.emit('status change', {
      id: change.fullDocument._id,
      status: status,           
      user: change.fullDocument.senderId,
   })
   }
  })
...
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, could you explain a bit about your answer, like the `pipeline`, `fullDocument`. I have also added my `Message` schema.

Comment: @dev1ce did you figure this out? Sorry, missed your response.

Comment: Nope, no luck. There must be something we could do, like, when we save a message to our db, we should get something like a Boolean, if it is successfully saved, then send/emit an event to client, if your network is slow/not working then it shouldn't. Something inside the `await message.save().then((response)=> ...).catch(...)`

Comment: @dev1ce I've created a quick mock-up [here](https://chapp1234.herokuapp.com). Is this close to what you're trying to do? 
Git: https://github.com/keonnicholas/chatapp
Disclaimers: rushed so code a bit messy.